# Excel 2007 not allowing users to enter 'Password to modify'

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, passwords, read-only

We have several Excel 2007 spreadsheets that have a password to modify set in them. Recently however they have not been allowing users to enter a password and have just been opening as Read Only straight away.

I've tried saving as a new file, and creating a completely new document and copying the contents but both efforts yielded the same results. Also, when I right click the file and view 'Properties', 'Read only' is not ticked.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: I did not apply any Windows updates yesterday (works servers, all updates are applied weekly on Tuesday nights). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See answer below, I thought I'd already added it, but obviously not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files were being accessed via a share, and another admin had inadvertently changed the permissions on that share to just 'Read' for all users that were not admins. Once it was change back to 'Full Permission', all went back to being fine.